# Eficientar Query Group by, Having - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql, rendimiento

Tengo la siguiente *query*:

```
SELECT S.IdCliente
    ,S.NOMBRE
    ,S.JLI_SDESLINEA
    ,S.JCA_SDESCATEGORIA
    ,SUM(S.MONTO) AS MONTO
    ,COUNT(*) AS QTY
    ,S.DIA
    ,T.IDTERRITORIO
    ,T.VENDEDOR
    ,T.SUPERVISOR
    ,V.IDCLIENTE
FROM Sabana S
LEFT JOIN CLIENTES C ON S.IDCLIENTE = C.IDCLIENTE
    AND C.RC = 90
LEFT JOIN TERRITORIOS T ON C.TERRITORIO = T.IDTERRITORIO
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT X.IDCLIENTE
    FROM SABANA X
    WHERE X.MONTO > 0
        AND X.PERIODO IN (
            201708
            ,201707
            ,201706
            )
    GROUP BY X.IDCLIENTE
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT X.PERIODO) = 3
    ) AS V ON V.IDCLIENTE = S.IDCLIENTE
WHERE S.MONTO > 0
    --AND V.IDCLIENTE IS NOT NULL
    AND S.PERIODO IN (
        201708
        ,201707
        ,201706
        )
GROUP BY S.IdCliente
    ,S.NOMBRE
    ,S.JLI_SDESLINEA
    ,S.JCA_SDESCATEGORIA
    ,S.DIA
    ,T.IDTERRITORIO
    ,T.VENDEDOR
    ,T.SUPERVISOR
    ,V.IDCLIENTE
```

Al ejecutarla demora aproximadamente 2 minutos, lo cual está bien, pero necesito filtrar el resultado `null` de la columna `V.IDCLIENTE`, entonces intenté usar `INNER JOIN`, y demoró 30 minutos, con `IS NOT NULL` también demoró 30 minutos aprox.

¿Alguna idea para eficientar el tiempo?

Este es el plan de ejecución de la consulta de arriba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el plan de ejecución real de la consulta utilizando `INNER JOIN` en vez de `LEFT JOIN`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Marcelo, bienvenido a [es.so], talvés si pudieras crear un [mcve] sería más sencillo replicar el escenario con el cual estás trabajando y de esta forma poder identificar qué se puede mejorar en tu consulta.

Comment: @Flxtr, creo que no hay posibilidad de poder replicar un ejemplo válido para analizar en este caso, si tal vez ayudaría la definición de índices de cada tabla involucrada.

Comment: @Patricio puede ser que sí, si nos proporcionan algunos datos podemos, es posible que llegamos al resultado que el OP espera, a lo mejor con la definición de las tablas hagamos algo al respecto :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo trataría de ver formas de reescribir tu consulta y revisaría los índices en la tabla `Sabana` (debería tener uno en `IDCLIENTE`, `PERIODO`).

De todas formas, puedes tratar con esta consulta:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY IDCLIENTE ORDER BY PERIODO) RN
    FROM Sabana
    WHERE MONTO > 0
    AND PERIODO IN (201708,201707,201706)
)
SELECT 
FROM CTE S
LEFT JOIN CLIENTES C 
    ON S.IDCLIENTE = C.IDCLIENTE
    AND C.RC = 90
LEFT JOIN TERRITORIOS T 
    ON C.TERRITORIO = T.IDTERRITORIO
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CTE
             WHERE IDCLIENTE = S.IDCLIENTE
             AND RN = 3);
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, la consulta ahora demora 1min. aunque tengo indices separados para Cliente y Periodo.

Gracias